# How to enable php curl extension

Tags: php, curl

hello guys anybody tell me how to enable php extension in php script not from php.ini. if there is any function or method available or not

Thanks

Comment: Not possible, this would be a security flaw. If needed, check if CURL is enabled and ask the user to install it. `if (!function_exists("curl_init")) die("Please install CURL");`

Comment: It is not possible without installing/enabling from php ini file

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

> Follow below steps to enable CURL via the php.ini
>
> 1.Locate your PHP.ini file. (normally located at in the bin folder of your apache install e.g.)
>
> 2.Open the PHP.ini in notepad.
>
> 3.Search or find the following : ';extension=php_curl.dll'
>
> 4.Uncomment this by removing the semi-colon ';' before it.
>
> 5.Save and Close PHP.ini.
>
> 6.Restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/php.ini

add this:   extension=curl.so

Restart apache

So now the problem is solved